# How do i turn off server caching?

Tags: php, html

I have a WHM server running on a server, but i want to turn off server caching on my accounts.
I cant access the server where its running on, i also can't contact support for help.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you define why you'd want do do this? Is `caching` the right word for what you think of? Because if you Google it a little, you'll find more solutions to **allow** caching then **deny** it... Since it is usefull.

Comment: I have a forum running on my server, and when i post a thread i need to CTRL+F5 (Cache clean) to actually see the thread showing in the list of threads.

Comment: Does the forum really *supposed* to update itself on new post? Does it have something like a [iosocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO)? Anyway, you can check [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/leverage-browser-caching/) for a code chunck that I could not explain, but that allows to choose what can be cached and for how long... By file type.

Comment: By the way, if you have access to WHM, I think you probably have a root access. If so, you can do almost what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not posible to turn anything off if you dont have access to the server or the host of the server